# issue in loop of finding prime number in java

Tags: java, primes

I know the mistake here is in the for loop as it should be i=2 but if i put it as i=1 then why is it not entering in the loop .could someone dry run this code and tell me how exactly is this an issue

```
       if(n==2)
        { return true;} 

      for(int i=1;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++){
        if(n % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: `n % 1 == 0` is always true (for an integer `n`)

Comment: "could someone dry run this code" [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand the mathematics behind it. Any number (that is a whole number, without a fraction part like for example 1.5) will give the reminder 0 when divided by one:

```
n % 1 == 0
```

This condition will therefore always be true.
If your case, once you are at n = 1, you return false.
I suggest you print out the output at every line of your program, and you will see the behavior.

Comment: Thankyou, I got it now . I wasn't considering this situation Any number (that is a whole positive number) will give the reminder 0 when divided by one